# pdflatex not exiting despite -halt-on-error

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to compile a .tex file with pdflatex.
The file isn't totally valid - but this isn't the point here. One line causes the compilation to fail : `\RequirePackage{lastpage}` causes the following error `!LaTeX Error: file 'lastpage.sty' not found.`

But the issue is that pdflatex asks me for a substitute file to  use, rather than exiting.

Since the call to pdflatex is within some code, I don't want it to be hanging around waiting for some input when none will be provided. Therefore, I called pdflatex with the `-halt-on-error` option. But this didn't solve it, and pdflatex still expects an input.

Am I missing something with the `-halt-on-error` option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, `-halt-on-error` doesn't stop at missing files. You can combine it with `-interaction=nonstopmode`, though, like in

```
pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode file
```